# numpy: working on a subset of matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4x4 identity matrix in numpy and I want to scale the first 3 dimensions by a factor. Currently, the way I am doing it as follows:

```
# Some scaling factors passed as a parameter by the user
scale = (2, 3, 4)  
scale += (1,)  # extend the tuple
my_mat = scale * np.eye(4)
```

Out of curiosity, I was wondering if there is some way to do this without extending the tuple.

Comment: What do you mean by `"scale the first 3 dimensions"` here?

Comment: somehow you have to explain which dimension not to scale, so you need a line of code to do so. Why not the way you chose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quickly done with numpy [broadcasting rules](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and indexing

```
A = np.eye(4)
scale = [2, 3, 4]

A[:3, :3] *= scale
```